# HTTP requests to localhost through Expo

Tags: node.js, react-native, localhost, expo, ngrok

I am trying to perform HTTP requests from an Expo (React-Native) application to a node.js server running on my PC however I am having some trouble getting this working. I am using ngrok to expose the localhost and am using the ngrok server in the fetch but I continue to get a Network request failed upon my POST request.

I am creating my server as follows:

```
app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Application is listening on ${process.env.PORT}`);
  (async function () {
    const endpoint = await ngrok.connect(process.env.PORT);
    console.log(
      `Publicly accessible tunnel to localhost:${process.env.PORT} is available on ${endpoint}`
    );
  })();
});
```

where process.env.PORT is set to 3000. When i start my server up, it successfully connects and I am able to send HTTP requests through Postman and successfully see the data being injected to my mongoDB database.

Now, for my frontend fetch, I have the following code:

```
try {
  let response = await fetch(`https://0b02aa4f40e2.ngrok.io/signup`, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      email: this.state.email,
      password: this.state.password,
    }),
  })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((state) => this.setState(state));
  console.log(response);
} catch (err) {
  console.log("Fetch didnt work.");
  console.log(err);
}
```

where the fetch url is the url provided by ngrok upon server startup. Im just doing some basic post configuration and passing along some email/password i am inputting through the app. However, fetch always fails and i end up with the same error as follows:

```
Network request failed
- node_modules\whatwg-fetch\dist\fetch.umd.js:487:17 in setTimeout$argument_0
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:135:14 in _callTimer
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:387:16 in callTimers
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:425:19 in __callFunction
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:112:6 in __guard$argument_0
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:373:10 in __guard
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:111:4 in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue  
* [native code]:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
```

I am at a loss as to what im doing wrong here or what im missing.

I am using my iPhone to test. I have the android simulator setup but haven't tried it yet figuring it would yield the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the metro bundler connection mode set to LAN and I had to change it to tunnel and now it works when I provide it the ngrok URL and am able to send post requests.